# Loop not stopping when array length met

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have it setup that the user inputs the array length. Then they are prompted to add the numbers to the array for let uses. The problem is that the prompted is stuck in an endless loop even though I think I have the do while loop set right, but apparently not. here is the code:

```
        function startProcess() {
            var arraySize = document.getElementById("txtSize").value;

            alert("the value is " + arraySize);

            var myArray = arraySize;

            do {
                parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number").value);
            } while (myArray <= arraySize);
        }
```

If I can just get this one piece to work then everything else false into place. Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: Neither `myArray` nor `arraySize` ever change, so when do you expect the loop to stop? Also, you never seem to do anything with what the user inserts.

Answer (score 6):

At this part:

```
var myArray = arraySize;

do {
     parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number").value);    
} while (myArray <= arraySize);
```

you set `myArray` to `arraySize`, then you run then loop while `myArray` (which has been set to `arraySize`) is lower or equal to `arraySize`, and obviously, it will always be equal.

Answer (score -1):

.value results are string not numbers.You need to convert it to integer
with parseInt()

```
 function startProcess() {
            var arraySize = document.getElementById("txtSize").value;

            alert("the value is " + arraySize);




            var myArray =parseInt(arraySize);

                do {parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number").value);

            } while (myArray <= arraySize);




            }
```

Comment: Yes you are right.None of the variables are changing so loop forever

Comment: If I am understanding your correctly, the issue is in arraySize code? it is not getting this information and carrying down to the loop?